# vectors iteration compiles to very different instructions

Tags: c++, loops

I am surprised that iterating over a vector with up to date compilers show a very different code for the same result.
Here is the code:

```
void fun1(vector <uint8_t> &a,unsigned num) {

    for (auto &&value : a) {
        value += num;
    }
}

void fun2(vector <uint8_t> &a,unsigned num){

    for (uint32_t x = 0, p = a.size(); x < p; x++){
        a[x] += num;
    }
}
void fun4(vector <uint8_t> &a,unsigned num){

    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < a.size(); x++){
        a[x] += num;
    }
}
void fun3(vector <uint8_t> &a,unsigned num) {

    for (auto it = a.begin(); it!=a.end(); ++it) {
        *it += num;
    }
}
void fun5(vector <uint8_t> &a,unsigned num) {

    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [num](auto &&val) {
        val += num;
    });
}
```

You can run it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/wQf0D4).

The generated assembly is very different (fun1 && fun5 even have proposal for SIMD). I get that for fun4 since a.size() may change. But the others? Different compilers approximate to the same result.

The compiler should be able to generate the same code since, the intent here is really basic (and the same).

**I really like fun2 version. Any way to improve it?**

### Update:

When giving enough info to the compiler, this becomes a non issue. So it tells that the compilers in their current version (gcc 9.x) are tailored differently for those loops when only partial info is accessible.

The code is still NOT the same but they all propose vectorization now. We will have to accept it I guess.
**Maybe** future versions will improve that.

[See the updated code (with useless allocations, but still)](https://godbolt.org/z/BUhPST)

Comment: Looking at the assembly is nice and all but really only tells half the story. What are the respective timings on what CPU?

Comment: Try with other types than (unsigned) `char` (and as extend `uint8_t`). they are less "strict" with aliasing. [uint32_t demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1gZLMs) are more similar.

Comment: @rubenvb: I can understand your remark, but still, the code should be the same for the same intent.

Comment: @Jarod42: with the uint32_t type only, they all generate the same code, except, obviously fun4. Interesting, but it shouldn't..

Comment: "It shouldn't". Unclear what you mean here.

Comment: Ah, there you go: Compiler shouldn't generate different code for fun1, 2, 3 and 5.

Comment: `char*` might alias any pointer, making optimization harder. (as you said `a.size()` might have changed in `func4`, with aliasing, it is worst) `a.data()` might point to other variable.

Comment: @Jarod42: comment on point ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Compilers now optimize code for out-of-order execution. The same C++ code can be compiled to different assembly code.
- So, try not to leave any space for an optimization :-)

Here are two the version of fun4:

```
void fun4_a(vector <uint8_t> &a, uint8_t num) {
    size_t n = a.size();
f1: if (n <= 0) goto f2;
    a[--n] += num;
    goto f1;
f2: return;
}

void fun4_b(vector <uint8_t> &a, uint8_t num) {
    size_t n = a.size();
    while (n > 0) a[--n] += num;
}
```

You can run it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/A9mfgS).

Compiler x86_64 gcc 9.1 produced the same assembly for fun4_a and fun4_b but still unrolled one 'add' loop:

```
fun4_a(std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, unsigned char):
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     ecx, esi
        sub     rax, rdx
        je      .L1
        sub     rax, 1
        add     BYTE PTR [rdx+rax], sil
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L1
.L3:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        sub     rax, 1
        add     rdx, rax
        add     BYTE PTR [rdx], cl
        test    rax, rax
        jne     .L3
.L1:
```

While compiler x86-64 icc 19.0.1 decided to produce more optimizations for fun4_b:

```
fun4_a(std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, unsigned char):
        mov       rcx, QWORD PTR [8+rdi]                        #806.26
        mov       rdx, rcx                                      #806.26
        mov       rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]                          #806.52
        sub       rdx, rax                                      #806.26
        je        ..B1.6        # Prob 18%                      #10.14
        xor       eax, eax                                      #10.5
..B1.3:                         # Preds ..B1.4 ..B1.2
        inc       rax                                           #10.5
        mov       r8, rcx                                       #9.11
        lea       r9, QWORD PTR [rax+rax]                       #9.11
        sub       r8, r9                                        #9.11
        neg       r9                                            #9.11
        add       r9, rdx                                       #9.11
        mov       rdi, r9                                       #9.11
        add       BYTE PTR [1+r8], sil                          #11.3
        inc       rdi                                           #9.11
        je        ..B1.6        # Prob 18%                      #10.14
        add       BYTE PTR [r8], sil                            #11.3
        test      r9, r9                                        #10.14
        jne       ..B1.3        # Prob 82%                      #10.14
..B1.6:                         # Preds ..B1.3 ..B1.4 ..B1.1
        ret                                                     #13.5
fun4_b(std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, unsigned char):
        mov       r8d, esi                                      #16.47
        mov       rsi, QWORD PTR [rdi]                          #806.52
        mov       rcx, QWORD PTR [8+rdi]                        #806.26
        sub       rcx, rsi                                      #806.26
        je        ..B2.17       # Prob 50%                      #18.16
        cmp       rcx, 16                                       #18.5
        jb        ..B2.18       # Prob 10%                      #18.5
        mov       rdx, rsi                                      #18.5
        and       rdx, 15                                       #18.5
        je        ..B2.9        # Prob 50%                      #18.5
        mov       rax, rdx                                      #18.5
        neg       rax                                           #18.5
        lea       rdx, QWORD PTR [16+rax]                       #18.5
        add       rax, 32                                       #18.5
        cmp       rcx, rax                                      #18.5
        jb        ..B2.18       # Prob 10%                      #18.5
        mov       rax, rcx                                      #18.5
        xor       r10d, r10d                                    #18.5
        sub       rax, rdx                                      #18.5
        mov       r9, rsi                                       #18.5
        and       rax, 15                                       #18.5
        neg       rax                                           #18.5
        add       rax, rcx                                      #18.5
        mov       edi, r8d                                      #18.20
..B2.7:                         # Preds ..B2.7 ..B2.6
        inc       r10                                           #18.5
        add       BYTE PTR [r9], dil                            #18.20
        inc       r9                                            #18.5
        cmp       r10, rdx                                      #18.5
        jb        ..B2.7        # Prob 82%                      #18.5
        jmp       ..B2.10       # Prob 100%                     #18.5
..B2.9:                         # Preds ..B2.3
        mov       rax, rcx                                      #18.5
        and       rax, 15                                       #18.5
        neg       rax                                           #18.5
        add       rax, rcx                                      #18.5
..B2.10:                        # Preds ..B2.7 ..B2.9
        movzx     edi, r8b                                      #18.29
        movd      xmm0, edi                                     #18.29
        punpcklbw xmm0, xmm0                                    #18.29
        punpcklwd xmm0, xmm0                                    #18.29
        punpckldq xmm0, xmm0                                    #18.29
        punpcklqdq xmm0, xmm0                                   #18.29
..B2.11:                        # Preds ..B2.11 ..B2.10
        movdqu    xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdx]                   #18.20
        paddb     xmm1, xmm0                                    #18.20
        movdqu    XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rsi], xmm1                   #18.20
        add       rdx, 16                                       #18.5
        cmp       rdx, rax                                      #18.5
        jb        ..B2.11       # Prob 82%                      #18.5
..B2.13:                        # Preds ..B2.11 ..B2.18
        add       rsi, rax                                      #18.5
        cmp       rax, rcx                                      #18.5
        jae       ..B2.17       # Prob 9%                       #18.5
..B2.15:                        # Preds ..B2.13 ..B2.15
        inc       rax                                           #18.5
        add       BYTE PTR [rsi], r8b                           #18.20
        inc       rsi                                           #18.5
        cmp       rax, rcx                                      #18.5
        jb        ..B2.15       # Prob 82%                      #18.5
..B2.17:                        # Preds ..B2.15 ..B2.1 ..B2.13
        ret                                                     #19.1
..B2.18:                        # Preds ..B2.2 ..B2.4
        xor       eax, eax                                      #18.5
        jmp       ..B2.13       # Prob 100%                     #18.5
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Your answer holds true. I updated the code and when run with the main and fwhole-program, the generated code is exactly the same. So I pointed an issue only arising with partial info (but it still should not have generated different code). Please see my update!

Comment: BTW, +1 for your answer.